# Optimising Table wrapping over a Select

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation, filtering

Suppose we have the following lists:

```
L0={{"a"}, {"a", "h"}, {"a", "d", "k", "r", "v"}, {"a", "b", "c", 
  "k"}, {"a", "b", "c", "s", "u"}, {"a", "b", "f", "t"}, {"a", "b", 
  "e", "l", "n", "o"}, {"a", "b", "d", "n", "o"}, {"a", "b", "d", "e",
   "n", "o"}, {"a", "b", "d", "e", "m", "n", "o", "t"}};
L1={{"a", "b"}, {"a", "c"}, {"a", "d"}, {"a", "e"}, {"a", "f"}};
```

The aim is to go through L0 for each pair in L1 and count how many times the given pair appears in L0 and categorise them into a polynomial with respect to lengths. I do as follow:

```
Table[Total[ 
  x^Map[Length, Select[L0, SubsetQ[ToLowerCase[#1], L1[[i]]] &]]], {i,
   Length[L1]}]
```

which gives:

```
{2 x^4 + 2 x^5 + 2 x^6 + x^8, x^4 + x^5, 2 x^5 + x^6 + x^8, 
 2 x^6 + x^8, x^4}
```

So to explain more clearly the first pair is `{"a","b"}`, and we see that `{"a","b"}` appears in elements that have length 4 in `L0` two times, two times in elements of size 5 and so on. I wonder how can I make this `Table` operation faster. This is a sample I'm showing here the main dataset has thousands of elements and there are thousands of curves.

Comment: I believe you've made a typo here: "we see that `{"a","b"}` appears in elements that have length 2 in L0 two times". Did you mean to say in elements that have length 4?

Comment: Oh yes that's a typo :) thanks

Comment: Not a problem :)

Comment: Does `L1` always consist of list of same length? Or is the `Length/@ L1` not constant?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher elements of L1 are always have length =2

Answer (score 6):

```
Map[Total[x^Cases[L0, p:{OrderlessPatternSequence[## & @@ #, ___]} :> Length[p]]] &]@L1
```

> {2 x^4 + 2 x^5 + 2 x^6 + x^8, x^4 + x^5, 2 x^5 + x^6 + x^8, 
>    2 x^6 + x^8, x^4}

Somewhat faster:

```
disPatch = Dispatch[{p : {OrderlessPatternSequence[## & @@ #, ___]} :> 
       x^Length[p], {__} -> Nothing} & /@ L1];
Total[Replace[L0, disPatch, 1], {2}]
```

> {2 x^4 + 2 x^5 + 2 x^6 + x^8, x^4 + x^5, 2 x^5 + x^6 + x^8, 
>    2 x^6 + x^8, x^4}

Answer (score 3):

To start off with, this has a 5-fold speed improvement on my machine. First, one helper function:

```
findIntersectionsByLength[a_, l_] := 
  Map[If[Intersection[a, #] == a, Length[#], 0] &, l];
```

This takes a set `a` and searches for all members of `l` for which `a` intersect `l[[i]]` is `a`. If there is a match, then it returns the length of the match, otherwise it returns 0, for each member of `l`.

Then we tally these intersections over `L0`, delete all of the 0 returns, replace them with the polynomial form, and total them, for each element of `L1`.  The `Sort` is included because `Intersection` sorts its results as well, so this ensures that it won't fail because `{"a","b"} != {"b","a"}`.

```
Table[Total[
  DeleteCases[
    Tally[findIntersectionsByLength[Sort[l], L0]], {0, _}] /. {e_?NumericQ, 
     n_?NumericQ} :> n x^e], {l, L1}]
```

To test this for larger samples, I generated a large sample `L0` as follows:

```
alphabet = 
 FromCharacterCode[
  List /@ ToCharacterCode["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]];
L0 = Table[
   RandomSample[alphabet, RandomInteger[{1, Length[Alphabet]}]], {i, 
    1, 1000000}];
```

Using the same `L1` as in the question, I get the following timings:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 res1 = Table[
    Total[x^Map[Length, 
       Select[L0, SubsetQ[ToLowerCase[#1], L1[[i]]] &]]], {i, 
     Length[L1]}];]
```

> {34.0179, Null}

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 res2 = Table[
    Total[DeleteCases[
       Tally[findIntersectionsByLength[Sort[l], L0]], {0, _}] /. {e_?
         NumericQ, n_?NumericQ} :> n x^e], {l, L1}];]
```

> {6.74027, Null}

```
res1 === res2
```

> True

Answer (score 3):

A bit ugly, but also works:

```
Dot[Power[x,First[#1]]& /@ Tally@(Length/@Cases[L0,Flatten@{___,First@#,___,Last@#,___}]),#[[2]]& /@ Tally@(Length/@Cases[L0,Flatten@{___,First@#,___,Last@#,___}])]& /@ L1
```

And seems to be quite quick. For the large sample @eyorble generated I get:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Dot[Power[x,First[#1]]& /@ Tally@(Length/@Cases[L0,Flatten@{___,First@#,___,Last@#,___}]),#[[2]]& /@ Tally@(Length/@Cases[L0,Flatten@{___,First@#,___,Last@#,___}])]& /@ L1]
```

> {0.623584, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

And for @eyorble's algorithm:

> {5.83138, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

For your example we get:

> {2 x^4 + 2 x^5 + 2 x^6 + x^8, x^4 + x^5, 2 x^5 + x^6 + x^8, 
>    2 x^6 + x^8, x^4}

, as required.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to employ `SparseArray`and thus, I convert the characters to integers in `Range[1,26]`. Actually, I start with integers and convert them to characters (just to be able to test against the original implementation).

```
n = 10000;
m = 100;
SeedRandom[1234];
LL0 = Table[RandomChoice[1 ;; 26, {RandomInteger[{1, 26}]}], {m}];
LL1 = RandomChoice[1 ;; 26, {n, 2}];
L0 = (FromCharacterCode[Partition[#, 1]]) & /@ (LL0 + 96);
L1 = (FromCharacterCode[Partition[#, 1]]) & /@ (LL1 + 96);
```

OP's implementation

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  result1 = 
    Table[Total[
      x^Map[Length, 
        Select[L0, SubsetQ[ToLowerCase[#1], L1[[i]]] &]]], {i, 
      Length[L1]}];
  ]
```

> 11.3748

eyorblade's implementation:

```
findIntersectionsByLength[a_, l_] :=  Map[If[Intersection[a, #] == a, Length[#], 0] &, l];

result2 = 
   Table[Total[
     DeleteCases[
       Tally[findIntersectionsByLength[Sort[l], L0]], {0, _}] /. {e_?
         NumericQ, n_?NumericQ} :> n x^e], {l, L1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> 2.9406

My implementation:

```
cf = Compile[{{len, _Integer, 1}, {idx, _Integer, 1}},
   If[Length[idx] == 1,
    Most[{0}],
    Part[len, Most[idx]]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

First@AbsoluteTiming[
  len0 = Length /@ LL0;
  len1 = Length /@ LL1;
  With[{
    i = Join @@ LL0,
    j = Join @@ ((0 LL0 + 1) Range[Length[LL0]])
    },
   A0 = SparseArray[Transpose[{i, j}] -> 1, {26, Length[LL0]}]
   ];
  With[{
    i = Join @@ ((0 LL1 + 1) Range[Length[LL1]]),
    j = Join @@ LL1
    },
   A1 = SparseArray[Transpose[{i, j}] -> 1, {Length[LL1], 26}]
   ];
  B = With[{A = A1.A0},
    ArrayFlatten[{
      {
       Ramp[SparseArray[A - SparseArray[len1 - 1] Unitize[A]]], 
       SparseArray[ConstantArray[1, {Length[A], 1}]]
       }
      }]
    ];
  data = cf[len0, B["AdjacencyLists"]];
  result3 = Total[x^data, {2}];
  ]
```

> 0.190386

Its result does not coincide with OP's but at least with eyorblade's one:

```
result1 === result2
result1 === result3
result2 === result3
```

> False
>
> False
>
> True

I don't know where the problem is...

I'd like to point out that 2/3 of the computation time is wasted for doing symbolic manipulations:

```
result3 = Total[x^data, {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.127073

The coefficient arrya can be generated much faster:

```
cg = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {l, _Integer}},
   Table[n, {l}],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];

SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}];
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  coeffarray = With[{
      i = Join @@ cg[Range[Length[data]], Length /@ data],
      j = Join @@ data
      },
     SparseArray[Transpose[{i, j}] -> 1, {n, 26}]
     ];
  ]
```

> 0.022717

Testing the coefficient array:

```
coeffarray.Table[x^k, {k, 1, 26}] == result3
```

> True

So, if one decides to settle with the coefficient array, the code can be made about 120 times faster for this input.

## Remarks

I added the all-1-column `SparseArray[ConstantArray[1, {Length[A], 1}]]}` to `B` so that `cf` gets never fed an empty list (`{}`) as second argument; compiled functions don't like that.